# Compile/Pre-compile global.asax only

Tags: c#, asp.net, compilation, global-asax, precompile

Is there a way to compile or precompile just the global.asax file to a dll and use it in the bin folder?

I have a license logic in this file and other files won't be compiled by me.

I could also check if the dll itself exists in bin folder.

```
void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       //Application is allowed to run only on specific domains
       string[] safeDomains = new string[] { "localhost" };
       if(!((IList)safeDomains).Contains(Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_NAME"]))
       {
           Response.Write("Thisweb application is licensed to run only on: "
           + String.Join(", ", safeDomains));
           Response.End();
       }
    }
```

Comment: Is that any better than compiling your licence code to an assembly and referencing that from global.asax (and/or web.config)? I assume there's utility stuff in there too so they can't just delete it and work without it?

Comment: People can decompile it anyway but this kind of people are very limited :)

Comment: @HasanGürsoy Did you find time to try my suggested approach?

Answer (score 3):

You can separate the code from your global.asax file by specifying the Inherits attribute on the Application directive. Now you don't have to write code in the Global.asax file.

```
<%@ Application Inherits="Company.LicensedApplication" %>
```

In fact, that is the only line of code that you need in Global.asax. Instead you need a separate C# file in which to write the code for your application class:

```
namespace Company
{
    public class LicensedApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Check license here
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can install the web application with the compiled application class in the bin folder.

Comment: how can we trigger compilation of this file from any page